# boost::interprocess message queue throw error

Tags: c++, boost, ipc, message-queue, boost-interprocess

I am using boost interprocess message queue in windows, however I met a issue that it will throw an error when max_msg_size doesn't equals to buffer_size,part of my code is as below:

```
//process A
message_queue::remove(name);
m_MQ = std::make_unique<message_queue>(create_only, name,2000,300);
m_MQ->try_send(buffer, buffer_size, 0);

//process B
m_MQ = std::make_unique<message_queue>(open_only, name);
m_MQ->try_receive(buffer, buffer_size, recvd_size, priority);
```

In this case, if `buffer_size` doesn't equal to 300, it will throw `boost::interprocess_exception::library_error` and I cannot pass variable length buffer any more.
Thanks so much.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52079547/boost-interprocess-message-queue-and-fork/52088610#52088610

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you state...

> if buffer_size doesn't equal to 300, it will throw
>   boost::interprocess_exception::library_error

Do you really mean "not equal to" or does the exception occur only when the buffer size is *less than* the stated maximum message size?

If the exception only occurs if `buffer_size < 300` then I think that's to be expected -- the library can't reliably receive a message that may be up to 300 `char`s into a buffer that's smaller than 300 `char`s in size.

Instead you should make use of [`boost::interprocess::message_queue::get_max_msg_size`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/message_queue_t.html#idp62961424-bb) to create a suitably size receiving buffer...

```
m_MQ = std::make_unique<message_queue>(open_only, name);
std::vector<char> buffer(m_MQ->get_max_msg_size());
m_MQ->try_receive(buffer.data(), buffer.size(), recvd_size, priority);
```