# boost::interprocess::message_queue no message received in second process

Tags: c++, boost

I am using boost's message queue to write a basic class with just two char arrays, but the data is not being received in the second process is empty, even though `get_num_msg()` returns 1 before the read and returns 0 after reading. For debugging purposes I also tried writing and reading from the same process, and that worked fine. I am using the shared pointer because earlier while just reading and writing integers, it would not read the integer at the receiver unless it was declared as shared ptr.

#### AccessQueue

```cpp
class AccessQueue {
    public:
    char name[64];
    char action[64];
    AccessQueue(char name[64], char action[64]) {
        strcpy(this->name, name);
        strcpy(this->action, action);
    }
    AccessQueue() {}
};
```

#### sending function

```cpp
// std::shared_ptr<AccessQueue> p1;
this->p1.reset(new AccessQueue("asd", "vsq"));
try {
    this->mq->send(&p1, sizeof(p1), 0);
} catch(boost::interprocess::interprocess_exception & ex) {
    std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
}
```

#### receiving function

```cpp
std::cout << this->mq->get_num_msg() << "\t" << this->mq->get_max_msg_size() << "\t" << this->mq->get_max_msg() << std::endl;
AccessQueue * a;
unsigned int priority;
boost::interprocess::message_queue::size_type recvd_size;
try {
    this->mq->try_receive(&a, sizeof(AccessQueue), recvd_size, priority);
} catch(boost::interprocess::interprocess_exception & ex) {
    std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
}
std::cout << this->mq->get_num_msg() << "\t" << this->mq->get_max_msg_size() << "\t" << this->mq->get_max_msg() << std::endl;
std::cout << "It clearly maybe works " << a->action << "\t" << a->name << std::endl;
```

#### output at receiver's end:

```
1       128     20
0       128     20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like p1 (in the sending function) is a smart pointer (like `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`). In that case

```
this->mq->send(&p1, sizeof(p1), 0);
```

is obviously wrong, because it puts the **pointer object** on the queue, instead of the data structure. Use

```
this->mq->send(*p1, sizeof(*p1), 0);
```

Or, indeed, don't use dynamic allocation in the first place:

```
AccessQueue packet("asd", "vsq");
mq.send(&packet, sizeof(packet), 0);
```

---

### Uhoh there's more

On the receiving side, there's a similar problem:

```
    AccessQueue * a;
    // ..
    mq.try_receive(&a, sizeof(AccessQueue), ...);
```

That receives INTO the pointer, not the object. You don't even have an object, because `a` (the pointer) is never initialized. Here the fix is syntactically simple:

```
    AccessQueue a;
```

No more pointers. Now, `a` is an object and `&a` is the address of that object.

> Note how the original was [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because you read `sizeof(AccessQueue)` bytes into a pointer. However the pointer is only 8 bytes and the struct is 128 bytes. Ooops!

### Simplified Working Demo

This works:

**[Live On Wandbox¹](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9WcpoifVx6ddmIJr)**

```
#include <boost/interprocess/ipc/message_queue.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

namespace bip = boost::interprocess;
using MQ = bip::message_queue;

template<size_t N>
static inline void safe_copy(std::array<char, N>& dst, std::string_view src) {
    std::copy_n(src.data(), std::min(src.size(), N), dst.data());
    dst.back() = 0; // make sure of NUL termination
}

struct AccessQueue {
    std::array<char, 64> name{0};
    std::array<char, 64> action{0};

    AccessQueue(std::string_view n = "", std::string_view a = "") {
        safe_copy(name, n);
        safe_copy(action, a);
    }
};

static_assert(std::is_standard_layout_v<AccessQueue>);

struct X {
    void send() {
        AccessQueue packet("asd", "vsq");
        try {
            mq.send(&packet, sizeof(packet), 0);
        } catch(std::exception const & ex) {
            std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
        }
    }

    AccessQueue receive() {
        AccessQueue retval;
        
        report();
        try {
            unsigned int priority;
            MQ::size_type recvd_size;
            mq.try_receive(&retval, sizeof(AccessQueue), recvd_size, priority);
        } catch(std::exception const & ex) {
            std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
        }
        report();
        return retval;
    }

    void report() {
        std::cout << mq.get_num_msg() << "\t" << mq.get_max_msg_size() << "\t" << mq.get_max_msg() << std::endl;
    }

    MQ mq { bip::open_or_create, "somequeue", 10, sizeof(AccessQueue) };
};

int main() {
    X tryit;
    tryit.send();
    auto const& [name, action] = tryit.receive();

    std::cout << std::quoted(name.data()) << " " << std::quoted(action.data()) << std::endl;
}
```

Prints

```
1       128     10
0       128     10
"asd" "vsq"
```

Note

- using `std::array` over C arrays gives you copy semantics by default
- guard the POD-ness of AccessQueue
- make sure the members are initialized
- make sure the copies are safe
- make sure the copies are NUL-terminated always
- Don't use `new` or delete. [Why should C++ programmers minimize use of 'new'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new)
- make sure your receive buffer size matches the max_msg_size ([boost interprocess message_queue and fork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52079547/boost-interprocess-message-queue-and-fork/52088610#52088610))

¹ shared emmory is prohibited on Wandbox :(

Comment: Here's a demo of it in separate processes in case it helps: https://imgur.com/R5fwDhh (slightly [modified `main`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1giDsH026B5YFrYX) to accept commandline argument)

Comment: thank you. Are boost tcp sockets better than (higher throughput) message queue if I were only doing IPC within the system? (I am trying to create a caching solution to be used with nodejs as an addon)

Comment: I'd say IPC on the same machine I'd say shared memory is likely the fastest (synchronization like between threads in the same process: even lockfree options exist). Message-Queueing has strictly more features than sockets (the transactionality of delivery). So it makes sense that it is more costly, but you can't compare these.